# Error: MyUser matching query does not exist - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

I am trying to include the username in the url, but I can no longer logout without getting this error:

[image]

It traces back to this line in views.py:

```
u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my views.py:

```
@login_required
def account_home(request, username):
u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
return render(request, "accounts/account_home.html", {})

def auth_logout(request):
logout(request)
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('accounts.views',
# url(r'^account/$', 'account_home', name='account_home'),
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', 'account_home', name='account_home'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'auth_logout', name='logout'),
url(r'^login/$', 'auth_login', name='login'),
url(r'^register/$', 'auth_register', name='register'),
)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried changing the username parameter to something like "user" so that it doesn't clash when you define u?

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like? It looks like you're trying to use the `account_home` view in a context in which the username is missing or incorrect, probably as a result of redirecting to `/` after logging out.

Comment: I am redirecting to "/" after logging out. Where should I have it redirected to? @PeterDeGlopper I added my urls.py as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your url matching regular expressions. Django uses the first matching pattern, and `/logout/` matches `r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$'` - it's looking for a user named `logout`.

You can either reorder your url patterns to put the username pattern at the end, or (a better solution) put something unambiguous in your pattern like `r'^/account/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$'`.

Answer (score 2):

Django uses the first view that matches your query. As your `account_home` view is the first view in the list, and it matches `/logout/`, `/login/` and `/register/`, all these url's are directed at the `account_home` view. As you don't have a user with those names, you get that error.

To fix it, the very least you need to do is move the `account_home` view to the end of the list. You probably also want to add some code that properly handles non-existent users, e.g. [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Comment: Obviously we agree on the cause, and `get_object_or_404` is a good practice - although in this case it would have left the user with a different problem.